# express session not persisting after deploying to heroku and netlify

Tags: node.js, express, session, heroku

I deployed my React frontend to netlify, and express backend to Heroku, and I'm using session.

The session works perfectly locally to it doesn't work when I deploy it

When I check the db, session has been made, but when I `console.log(req.session)` it doesn't logs anything

So, it looks like the session is saved on db, but it doesn't save on the heroku server

Do I need to configure sessions on heroku?

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mydburl",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }
);

const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri:
    "mydburl",
  collection: "sessions",
});

app.use(
  cors({
    domain: url,
    origin: [url],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  session({
    key: "userID",
    secret: "subscribe",
    proxy: true,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
      maxAge: null, //1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 1 week
      domain: url,
    },
  })
);

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    res.send({ isLogin: true, user: req.session.user });
  } else {
    console.log("req.session.user doesn't exist");
    res.send("no");
  }
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  RegisterModel.find({ username }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (error, response) => {
        if (response) {
          req.session.user = result;
          res.send(result);
        } else {
          res.send("비밀번호가 맞지 않습니다");
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.send("아이디가 맞지 않습니다");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It would really help if you could also add the Front-End part where you are creating the session. But I think combing the front-end and back-end should help you solve this problem.

Deploy both front-end and back-end on Heroku. Change your `index.js` or `server.js` whichever is your entry-point of the server to something like this:

```
...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));

module.exports = { app };
```

Here, I have assumed that your front-end part is inside the client folder. You can change it accordingly.

```
root_folder
   -server.js
   ....rest of server files
   package.json
   -client
        -build
        ....rest of React part
        package.json
```

Also, add this to your package.json file of server.

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

The above command will install the client dependencies first and then create a build for deploying.

Now, if check Heroku URL is https://xyz.herokuapp.com and it should display your front-end and the rest will work the same. Locally you can check this by manually creating a build(npm run build) and changing `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"` to `process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"`, also change the `build`  folder path accordingly. Now, check `http://localhost:5000` or your local backend server URL.

You can read more about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#heroku

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I should try to combine those and try your code!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works after combining client and server!